# How can I use LEFT JOIN with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following Sequelize relations:

```
Shop.hasMany(ShopAd, {foreignKey : 'shop_id', as : 'ads'});
ShopAd.belongsTo(Shop, {foreignKey : 'id'})
```

For the following Sequelize query:

```
Shop.findAll({
    where: {id:shopId},
    include: [{model:ShopAd, as:'ads', where:{is_valid:1, is_vertify:1}}]
}).success(function(result) {
    callback(result);
});
```

the SQL that Sequelize runs for this query is:

```
SELECT `Shop`.`id`, `Shop`.`user_id`, `Shop`.`short_name`, `Shop`.`description`, `Shop`.`tips`, `Shop`.`city`, `Shop`.`province`, `Shop`.`address`, `Shop`.`logo`, `Shop`.`publicity_photo`, `Shop`.`taobao_link`, `Shop`.`is_vertify`, `Shop`.`create_time`, `Shop`.`update_time`, `ads`.`id` AS `ads.id`, `ads`.`shop_id` AS `ads.shop_id`, `ads`.`pic_url` AS `ads.pic_url`, `ads`.`description` AS `ads.description`, `ads`.`link` AS `ads.link`, `ads`.`is_valid` AS `ads.is_valid`, `ads`.`is_vertify` AS `ads.is_vertify`, `ads`.`create_time` AS `ads.create_time`, `ads`.`update_time` AS `ads.update_time` FROM `weshop_shop` AS `Shop`
INNER JOIN `weshop_shop_advertsing` AS `ads` ON `Shop`.`id` = `ads`.`shop_id` AND `ads`.`is_valid`=1 AND `ads`.`is_vertify`=1 WHERE `Shop`.`id`='1';
```

which does an `INNER JOIN`.

I want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead. How can I do this with Sequelize?

Answer (score 93):

using:
`required:false`

sentences：

```
Shop.findAll({
     where:{id:shopId}, 
     include:[
         { model:ShopAd, as:'ads', 
           where:{ 
                 is_valid:1, 
                 is_vertify:1},   
           required:false
           }
         ]
      })
      .success(function(result) {
        callback(result);
    });
```

Comment: but how can LEFT JOIN can be forced in the declaration of the relation?

Answer (score 32):

> `required: true` forces an `INNER JOIN`, use `required: false` to force a `LEFT JOIN`.

Taken from [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3936#issuecomment-112082519).