# How can I write left join on Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am writing API on Node.js
I have 2 tables transactions, users.
Transactions table record a transaction who send money to whom and price.
I want to get transaction and users nickname by single query.
How can I make query and sequelize?

transactions

```
+--------------+------------+-----------+
| from_user_id | to_user_id |     price |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
|            1 |          2 |       200 |
|            1 |          3 |       200 |
|            1 |          4 |       200 |
|            1 |          5 |       200 |
|            2 |          1 |       200 |
|            2 |          3 |       200 |
|            2 |          4 |       200 |
|            2 |          5 |       200 |
|            3 |          1 |       200 |
|            3 |          2 |       200 |
|            3 |          4 |       200 |
|            3 |          5 |       200 |
|            4 |          1 |       200 |
|            4 |          2 |       200 |
|            4 |          3 |       200 |
|            4 |          5 |       200 |
|            5 |          1 |       200 |
|            5 |          2 |       200 |
|            5 |          3 |       200 |
|            5 |          4 |       200 |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

users

```
+----+----------+
| id | nickname |
+----+----------+
|  1 | umi      |
|  2 | minato   |
|  3 | haruto   |
|  4 | rikuto   |
|  5 | yamato   |
+----+----------+
```

I want to get result below;

```
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| id | from_user_id |  nickname  | to_user_id |  nickname  |     price |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |            1 |        umi |          2 |     minato |       200 |
|  2 |            1 |        umi |          3 |     haruto |       200 |
|  3 |            1 |        umi |          4 |     rikuto |       200 |
|  4 |            1 |        umi |          5 |     yamato |       200 |
|  5 |            2 |     minato |          1 |        umi |       200 |
|  6 |            2 |     minato |          3 |     haruto |       200 |
|  7 |            2 |     minato |          4 |     rikuto |       200 |
|  8 |            2 |     minato |          5 |     yamato |       200 |
|  9 |            3 |     haruto |          1 |        umi |       200 |
| 10 |            3 |     haruto |          2 |     minato |       200 |
| 11 |            3 |     haruto |          4 |     rikuto |       200 |
| 12 |            3 |     haruto |          5 |     yamato |       200 |
| 13 |            4 |     rikuto |          1 |        umi |       200 |
| 14 |            4 |     rikuto |          2 |     minato |       200 |
| 15 |            4 |     rikuto |          3 |     haruto |       200 |
| 16 |            4 |     rikuto |          5 |     yamato |       200 |
| 17 |            5 |     yamato |          1 |        umi |       200 |
| 18 |            5 |     yamato |          2 |     minato |       200 |
| 19 |            5 |     yamato |          3 |     haruto |       200 |
| 20 |            5 |     yamato |          4 |     yamato |       200 |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can use LEFT JOIN at Sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561915/how-can-use-left-join-at-sequelize)

Comment: Thanks, I could not understand the model of Shop, ShopAd.